# chrome devtools mobile emulation preset in link

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to know whether Chrome emulation settings could be sent via a simple link.

**Scenario**

- Apply some Emulation parameters such as Model : "Apple Iphone 5"....
- Send page link by mail for a population of non developer.

**Example**

- link of my page is `/page`
- would become `/page?model=....&....&orientation=`

Or such a similar solution.

Thank you.

Jul

Answer (score 0):

Device emulation should not have anything to do with the URL modification, which can potentially break the original URL (consider `/page?model=X5`).

Comment: ok thanks for explanation, but a simple load device emulation configuration loaded with an entry menu for instance would have been nice.